# "Yet" vs "so far" again!

Tags: word-choice

This question was previously answered very effectively on this forum a few years ago in terms of Negative Polarity, and the use of "yet" being limited to negative declarative sentences or interrogative sentences. But the following sentence from my non-native English speaking friend has me confused:

- I just started to study the language, so I can hardly speak English *so far*.

To me this should be a "yet" sentence but I'm not sure why. Is this a type of negative polarity even though the word "no" isn't included? Or am I just wrong, with "so far" the correct choice?

Comment: There are yet many uses of *yet* over *so far*. I may yet have other ideas later. So far, the student has begun studies and cannot say much. Wouldn't want to say he made zero advances so far, for he just started. *So far* measures how far the accomplishment to this point. I'd say he can hardly speak yet - but that's not ideal either. Time to reword.

Comment: 'So far' and 'yet' are often interchangeable. 'I can speak hardly any English so far / yet' is a better way to phrase this. Here, 'hardly' is the negative polarity **trigger**. But note that 'so far' isn't necessarily a NPI: 'I'm learning exo-languages. I've mastered Klingon, Vulcan, Rigellian and Desplainian so far.'

Comment: One can always simply refer to the time without expressing one's expectations. _So far_ is perfectly fine, and so is _yet_, since _hardly_ is a negative trigger.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler commented:

> One can always simply refer to the time without expressing one's expectations. *So far* is perfectly fine, and so is *yet,* since *hardly* is a negative trigger.